# fgetc fails to load last character of file

Tags: c, file-io, linked-list, fgetc

I am trying to load a file into my program so I can work with the bytes on an individual basis, but when I am loading the file it stops loading prematurely; always by 1 character. If there is only one character in the file it does not load it. Is the problem with how I am reading the file or is it in a different location?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {//linked list structure, I use this because I am working with files of vastly varying length
    char val;
    struct node *next;
} data;

void printdata(data *head);
void freeData(data **head);
data* readFile(FILE *f);

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {//set this up so it is easier to test
    if(argc == 2) {
        FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        data *d = readFile(f);
        fclose(f);
        printdata(d);
        freeData(&d);
    }
}

data* readFile(FILE *f) {//This is the function containing the problem
    data *retVal = malloc(sizeof(data));
    data *cur = retVal;
    int c = fgetc(f);
    if(c != EOF) {
        retVal->val = (char) c;
        while((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
            cur->next = malloc(sizeof(data));
            cur->next->val = (char) c;
            cur = cur->next;
        }
    } else return NULL;//EDIT: was in a rush and forgot to add this.
    cur->next = NULL;
    return retVal;
}

void freeData(data **head) {
    if((*head)->next != NULL) freeData(&((*head)->next));
    free(*head);
}

void printdata(data *head) {
    data *cur = head;
    do {
        printf("%c", cur->val);
        cur = cur->next;
    } while(cur->next != NULL);//EDIT: I changed this because there was a small "problem" that was not the real problem
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: The problem is in your `printdata` function, it doesn't print the last element in the list.

Comment: Your design doesn't work correctly for empty files. It will return a single node that has an uninitialized value in `val`.

Comment: Did it produce any error?

Comment: no this did not produce any errors. It just stops reading early. This is a compileable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printdata()` stops too soon. [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36659174/fgetc-fails-to-load-last-character-of-file/36660356#comment60911144_36659174)

Do not stop when `cur->next == NULL`.  Stop when `cur == NULL`

```
void printdata(data *head) {
  data *cur = head;
  while (cur) {
    printf(" <%hhx>", cur->val);  // Changed format for debugging
    fflush(stdout);               // Useful for debugging
    cur = cur->next;
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

---

Also included is a simplified `readFile()`.

```
data* readFile(FILE *f) { //This is the function containing the problem
  data head; // Only next field used
  data *cur = &head;
  int c;
  while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
      cur->next = malloc(sizeof *(cur->next));
      cur = cur->next;
      assert(cur);
      cur->val = (char) c;
    }
  cur->next = NULL;
  return head.next;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the function printdata()

```
void printdata(data *head) {
    data *cur = head;
    while(cur->next != NULL) {
        printf("%c", cur->val);
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Notice that when

```
cur->next == NULL
```

The command inside the while will **NOT** be executed.

Also notice that this always happens at the last element. So your code won't print the last data.

Among other solutions, you could use a do-while loop:

```
do{
  printf("%c", cur->val)
  cur = cur->next;
} while (cur->next != NULL);
```

This will guarantee that the last element will printed, because the while will stop **AFTER** the inside of the loop is executed for the last element.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is not the problem, I tried the change and the problem still exists in the same exact way. though thanks anyway

Comment: That's unfortunate. I do believe the "do while" is a improvement, but I understand if it is not the root of the problem. I'm burned out tonight, but if your problem stands by tomorrow I'll take another look!